# KDE 5 - How to remove a system tray entry?

Tags: kde, kde-plasma-5

I've just upgrade to Kubuntu 16.04 and there's an icon in system tray which is not displaying normally.

[image]

It can be hidden from the system tray entries settings but I'd like to figure out which application it is, and if it's an application no longer available I want to remove it completely.

Where can I find the configuration file for KDE 5?

Answer (score 4):

The configuration file is:

`~/.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc`

Whithin this file you can find a section listing all showed icons.
Here you can remove what you wan't view.

To detect the mentioned section, look for a [Containment] containing  `plugin=org.kde.plasma.private.systemtray`

When you've removed what you want, simply kill plasmashell

`killall plasmashell`

and restart it

`kstart plasmashell`

Comment: This is great, however after a reboot this file gets overwriten